Shade a specific tab if a value on that tab is equal to a value
Victim of my own inexperience here. I need a function that:

Only runs on a sheet that I specify
Runs whenever the sheet is opened
Checks the value of a cell and shades that specific tab a color based on the value of the cell.

I've been reading posts since yesterday and have duct-taped this together from similar questions:
function onOpen(e) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ss.getSheets().forEach(sh => {
    if(sh.getRange("E2").isBlank()) {
      sh.setTabColor("#00ff00");//green
    } else {
      sh.setTabColor("#ff8000");//orange
    }
  });
}

It works but it's certainly doing things it doesn't need for my purposes, I just lack the experience to know how to modify some parts of it correctly.

Can I change isBlank to search for a specific phrase? (isBlank works but I feel like a better-practice solution would be to have it key off a value).
Can I set this to run on only one sheet that I specify (not sure how to modify the forEach argument).

Apologies for asking and huge thanks to anyone who can help. I'm sure this is a simple set of arguments, but I'm the farthest thing from a programmer.

Using onOpen() to check and shade a specific cell on a sheet
It's possible to do what you'd like that will:


Only runs on a sheet that I specify
Runs whenever the sheet is opened
Checks the value of a cell and shades that specific tab  a color based on the value of the cell



Here is the code:
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ss.getSheets().forEach(sh => {
    var sn = sh.getSheetName();
    var vl = sh.getRange("E2").getValue();
    if (sn == "Sheet1") {
      if (vl == "Test") {
        sh.setTabColor("green");
      } else {
        sh.setTabColor("orange");
      }
    }
  });
}

When the sheet is opened, the script checks Sheet 1's E2 cell if its value  is Test and if it's true, sets the background to green. If not, it'll set it to orange.
Here's another way to write the code:
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  sh.getRange("E2").getValue() == "Test" ? sh.setTabColor("Green") : sh.setTabColor("Orange");
}

This uses getSheetByName() to get the sheet name and the shorthand version of if (Ternary Operator)

Output
If the text matches:

If the text didn't match:


References:

Simple Triggers
getSheetByName()


Thank you for responding so quickly! Is there a way I can modify this formula to change the color of the tab that the data is on instead of a cell/range? I tried to replace setBackground with setTabColor but it doesn't work.
I want the tab on the bottom bar to change color depending on whether the text value does/doesn't match. I tried to add a screenshot but can't seem to paste it in the comment. :(
Link to an example sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RU71lNNopBingMXNG6bO6C5pu3l3icQdnU78kkvuczs/edit?gid=1205176391#gid=1205176391
Thank you again for your help! :)

Update: I got it!
function onOpen() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Automated Links"); //feel free to change this to your sheet name
var rg = sh.getRange("E2")
var vl = rg.getValue();
vl == "pending" ? sh.setTabColor("Green") : sh.setTabColor("Orange")
}
(Makes sense that to modify the sheet you have to target the sheet variable! :) )
Thank you again so much for answering, this solved my question! \o/

My Apologies, that was my mistake. I'm glad that you were able to modify it to cater to your needs! I'll update my answer as well to match your initial question to my answer.
